# How do I shutdown Kafka and Zookeeper cleanly on Windows

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have spent a little time looking into Kafka on the back burner, and I have some interest in using it, but my potential use case is a bit non standard - I am interested in using kafka on a single machine (for now), in a somewhat ephemeral way.
Specifically, I want to launch zookeeper and kafka from a python program, connect, use it as it should be for event streams, and then shut everything down. At a later point, I want to be able to start things back up and connect to the old kafka instance, and read the topics that were previously written. This should be very do-able as long as I keep the config the same.

I have some proof of concept code for this in a near working state, but I can't seem to get Kafka or zookeeper to shut down cleanly. On windows, the batch script for stopping kafka just kills the process, which leaves zookeeper in a bad state. Likewise, the batch script for stopping zookeeper just kills the process, and means it can't launch in the right state to repair itself.
I have tried also sending ctrl+c events to kafka and zookeeper from python, as you would when you ran the scripts in a terminal, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Is there any way to cleanly shut down a programmatically launched instance of kafka and zookeeper on windows?

Answer (score 0):

> which leaves zookeeper in a bad state

Zookeeper doesn't rely on Kafka, so unclear what you're expecting to clear up here as the Znodes would remain (otherwise you'd lose all data if the broker restarted)

If you want to use Python (and Windows), I'd suggest creating managed Windows services and iteracting with them in `pywin32` that you can programmatically start/stop rather than `subprocess` calls. This would work similarly to Unix's `systemctl` calls (which respectfully call the `-start` and `-stop` shell scripts provided by Kafka)

Or you could [use WSL2](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/)